# read xml attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

i'm confused... nothing is on my mind anymore... i need to read each attribute from this kind of `xmldocument`

```
<party_list>
   <party currency="BAM" id="330-159210014235851" />
   <party currency="EUR" id="330-153990008540078" />
</party_list>
```

i have this... but unhelpful

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"e:\input\partylist.xml");
XElement root1 = doc.Element("party_list");
foreach (XElement element in root1.Elements())
{
   MessageBox.Show(element.Element("party").Value);
}
```

Comment: hi try out the solution is working now....might help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you can try this ?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"e:\input\partylist.xml");
foreach (var partyList in doc.Descendants("party"))
{
   string currency= partyList .Attribute("currency").Value;
   string id= partyList .Attribute("id").Value;
}
```

Comment: Note, that `NullReferenceException` is possible at `Attribute("currency").Value`. I also did access `Value` property, until I saw lazyberezovsky's answers with cast to `string`. Maybe it's a desired behavior to throw exception, but usually it isn't, because `xml` usually comes from external sources.

Comment: doc.Descendants("party_list") should be doc.Descendants("party")

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
MessageBox.Show(element.Element("party").Value);
```

with

```
MessageBox.Show((string)element.Attribute["currency"]);
```

because your element is already `party` element.

---

Full code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"e:\input\partylist.xml");
foreach (var party in doc.Descendants("party"))
   foreach (var attr in party.Attributes())
        MessageBox.Show(attr.ToString());
```

This code uses overridden `ToString()` method of `XAttribute` which returns attribute name with its value like this:

```
currency="BAM"
```

You can use only value, if you need: `MessageBox.Show(attr.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(...);
    for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {
        string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["id"].Value;
    }
```

Try above code.

Comment: have you put appropriate tag name in it?

Answer (score 0):

input xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
<party_list>
  <party currency='BAM' id='330-159210014235851' />
  <party currency='EUR' id='330-153990008540078' />
</party_list>
```

C# code to get attributre value

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"e:\input\partylist.xml");
        var eles = doc.Element("party_list").Elements("party");

        foreach (XElement ele in eles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (ele.Attribute("currency").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(ele.Attribute("id").Value);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string body = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?><party_list>
                    <party currency='BAM' id='330-159210014235851' />
                    <party currency='EUR' id='330-153990008540078' />
                </party_list>";
XmlDocument bodyDoc = new XmlDocument();
bodyDoc.LoadXml(body);
XmlNodeList xnList = bodyDoc.SelectNodes("/party_list/party");
foreach (XmlNode item in xnList)
{
    var id =  item.Attributes["id"].Value;
    var currency = item.Attributes["currency"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
XElement xml = 
  XElement.Parse (@"<party_list>
                      <party currency='BAM' id='330-159210014235851' /> 
                      <party currency='EUR' id='330-153990008540078' />
                    </party_list>");

xml.Elements()
     .SelectMany(element => element.Attributes().Select(attrib => attrib.Value))
       .ToList()
         .ForEach(text => MessageBox.Show(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
XDocument doc = XDpcument.Load("your xml location");

var parties = from p in doc.Descendants("party")
              select new 
              { 
                      currency = p.Attribute("currency").Value;
                      Id =       p. Attribute("id").Value;
              }
```